# Why this dynamically added select input using AJAX are not working?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I am getting form fields in HTML definition using an ajax call like this using Jquery in codeigniter view.

```
     function getaddinfo(){
          var modtabgrp = $("#modtabgrp").val();
             $.ajax({
                url:base_url+"Base/gridaddfetch?modtabgrp="+modtabgrp,
                async:false,
                cache:false,
                success :function(data) {
                $('#liveform').append(data);

              },
          }); 
       }
```

Now this response contains select2 plugin based inputs, I am able to show all the inputs correctly but the select2 inputs are not getting enabled. 
The function to enable the select2 plugin based input on add icon click is like this,

```
      $("#addicon").click(function(){
          $('#stateid').select2('val','2');
          $('#tabgropdropdown').select2('val','1');
        }
```

Also I have make sure that before clicking the #addicon Add button, The form is loaded and injected inside DOM tree. Then why the #stateid and #tabgropdropdown elements available in #liveform Div is not getting enabled?

In other words, Why the add button event related event is not getting bind with the dynamically added input elements?

Comment: Use  $(document).on('click','#addicon',function(){ **[...]** })

Comment: @Roy  I have tried this, but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to re-initialised the select2() for that input after calling the ajax.

```
function getaddinfo(){
          var modtabgrp = $("#modtabgrp").val();
             $.ajax({
                url:base_url+"Base/gridaddfetch?modtabgrp="+modtabgrp,
                async:false,
                cache:false,
                success :function(data) {
                $('#liveform').append(data);
                $('#stateid').select2();
                $('#tabgropdropdown').select2();  
              },
          }); 
}
```